# Error Trying to Create Array of Double Variable Type

Tags: java, arrays, loops, double

I'm trying to create a program which takes values that are doubles from the user and stores them in arrays before dividing them and rounding the answers. However I keep receiving errors trying to create double arrays.

```
 double n = sc.nextDouble();

    double a[] = new double[n];
    double b[] = new double[n];
    double roundedValues[] = new double[n];

    for (double i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the values you would like to divide as pairs of two numbers: ");
        // Read pair and store it inside i-th position of a and b arrays 
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        a[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number you would like to divide by: ");
        b[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        roundedValues[i] = Math.round(a[i] / b[i]);
    }
```

The error I'm getting where I've declared the arrays says:

> incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Comment: What does an array with a double number of elements mean? I've never seen an array with 3.2734 elements.

Comment: Why are you using double as your counter (i)?  Use int.

Comment: I've changed the control variable in the loop to int and that has solved that issue but i'm still getting the same error on the lines where I have declared the arrays. Can you help me understand why? I'd like to store values that are decimal numbers within the arrays I have created. Thanks

Comment: See Eran's comment.  You're still creating a[] and b[] with a "double" number of elements.  Anything in the the brackets needs to be an int.

Comment: OK. I'd like to store values that are decimal numbers within the arrays I have created, hence why I tried initialising the array as a double. I think I understand where I was going wrong, I thought that the int was responsible for the type of values that could be stored within the array. Is there a way I can store values that are of the type double within the array?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, variable `n`, defined as  `double n = sc.nextDouble();`  is a double. You can't make an array whose length is a double because then you might end up with half an element. Imagine an array 4.5 elements long!

Define `n` like one of these instead:

`int n = sc.nextInt()`
      or
`int n = (int)sc.nextDouble();`

Secondly, `i` is also a double! Define it like this:

`for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {`

That way the compiler knows that `i` is an integer and doesn't have to worry about needing to retreive an element at a `double` index, like the 4.2th element! (which doesn't, and shouldn't exist)

***Heres the fixed code:***
        `int n = sc.nextInt();`

```
double a[] = new double[n];
double b[] = new double[n];
double roundedValues[] = new double[n];

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the values you would like to divide as pairs of two numbers: ");
    // Read pair and store it inside i-th position of a and b arrays 
    System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
    a[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter second number you would like to divide by: ");
    b[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    roundedValues[i] = Math.round(a[i] / b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a[i] and b[i] expect int type, but you supply double to it
Should be 
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
```

and

```
 double n = sc.nextDouble();
   should be changed to:
 int n = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: The exception is coming from the fact that OP is using a double for n, and trying to declare that as the number of elements int he array declarations.

Comment: I've changed the control variable in the loop to int and that has solved that issue but i'm still getting the same error on the lines where I have declared the arrays. Can you help me understand why? I'd like to store values that are decimal numbers within the arrays I have created. Thanks

Comment: Change your `n` variable to an int and use `nextInt()` instead of `nextDouble()`